# how to send local attachments with twilio in MVC

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-php, twilio-twiml, twilio-click-to-call

I have to choose files and after that I want to send it to the whatsapp number using twilio in MVC.

I was going through some links but it was showing we can send attachment with `mediaurl`.

and `mediaurl` excepts urls starts with http or https,

but `mediaurl` do not  excepting urls starts with http.

is there any way to send local files/images to the whatsapp using twilio in C# or mvc

Thanks in Advance

Comment: not sure why media url option did not work for you? you should serve you files statically somewhere before attaching them to message. don't think you can send file directly

Comment: @Yegor Androsov mediaurl accepting links starts with http or https..then I have to upload file somewhere and then have to pass http or https at starting of the path?

Comment: exactly, you could serve them from website folder or upload to some external storage (Azure Blob Storage, AWS S3 Bucket etc.), then you get a link that can be sent using twilio api